# How to know if page is empty

Tags: macros

Looking for macro to know if the current page is empty ,  and  opening new page if were not as well.
 Is there any idea to do that? 
example in this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\border}{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \coordinate (top) at ($(current page.north)+(0,-1.5)$);
    \coordinate (bottom) at ($(current page.south)+(0,1.5)$);
    \coordinate (left) at ($(current page.west)+(1.5,0)$);
    \coordinate (right) at ($(current page.east)+(-1.5,0)$);
    \draw[red] (bottom-|left) rectangle (top-|right);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\border

\end{document}
```

I want to put the frame in a blank page after the text

Comment: Define "empty". No content but has a header/footer? How about creating a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that shows what you mean by "empty" and "not empty" in addition to the result from this condition.

Comment: i mean 'empty page' totally blank

Comment: You can insert `\newpage` or `\clearpage` to move to a blank page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess: `\newpage` is what you are looking for. It starts a new page, if there is something. Otherwise `\newpage` does not cause a page break.

Comment: @Heiko What's the difference between `\newpage` and `\clearpage`? When should one be used and not the other?

Comment: @Manuel, `\clearpage: macro:->\ifvmode \ifnum \@dbltopnum =\m@ne \ifdim \pagetotal <\topskip \hbox {}\fi \fi \fi \newpage \write \m@ne {}\vbox {}\penalty -\@Mi` As you can see, `\clearpage` makes use of `\newpage`.

Comment: @Manual `\clearpage` additionally flushes pending float objects.